# Java 7 Constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I saw that in `Java 7`, they introduced the method [`Objects.requireNonNull(T obj, String message)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull%28T,%20java.lang.String%29).

> Checks that the specified object reference is not null and throws a
>   customized`NullPointerException`if it is. This method is designed
>   primarily for doing parameter validation in methods and constructors
>   with multiple parameters.

Before starting to reformat my code, I would ask here to have some feedback about using that.

```
 public Foo(Bar bar, Baz baz) {
         /** Old one
         this.bar = bar;
         this.baz = baz;
         **/
         this.bar = Objects.requireNonNull(bar, "bar must not be null");
         this.baz = Objects.requireNonNull(baz, "baz must not be null");
   }
```

Is it a better practice to use it directly when I construct my object (I was thinking about if I create a library or other stuff for developers) ?

Or should I leave it as a "classic/old one" constructor ?

Comment: It depends. Do you want an exception thrown in your constructor?

Comment: Actually, if the exception isn't thrown in the constructor, it will certainly being thrown by calling methods of this class. The purpose of this is : should I directly prevent the user at the construction ("Be careful some objects are null so you won't be able to perform some methods") or do I let him to throw this exceptions himself (if he calls some methods of the class) ?

Comment: I've taken to using the Builder pattern here, and, as Ravi suggests below, throwing IllegalArgumentException (or IllegalStateException.)

Comment: I believe the requireNonNull thing might be a IntelliJ-IDEA feature isn't it?  Or isn't it related to annotations for nonNull in your classes?  If you need this feature and backwards compatibility is necessary to JDK1.6, then use Google Collections, which has some nonNull functions in it OR wait for JDK1.8?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you can see, there is disagreement whether an NPE or some other exception should be thrown<sup>1</sup>.

If you accept that an NPE is more appropriate than the alternatives, AND this is a situation where `null` is unequivocally incorrect, then:

- it is better to throw the NPE early; i.e. in the constructor, and
- it is better to throw it with a custom exception message; i.e. not a `null` as happens when the JVM throws NPEs.

In that context using `Objects.requireNonNull` is clearly good practice.

---

You could also use Java assertions for this, but you'd need to make a judgement as to whether it is a good or bad thing that the test *could* be turned off.  You have to consider whether the performance benefit of turning the early check off outweighs the problems that could be caused by not checking earlier.  For instance, suppose you see an NPE in production with assertions turned off ... and you can't diagnose it.  Do you turn on assertions?  Will the assertions *change* the behaviour of the code?  Will it slow your system down (due to lots of other assertion checks)?  Is the situation that triggered the NPE likely to recur?

(Threading-related bugs are often "once in a blue moon" things that are exceedingly difficult to reproduce.  I would argue that you need the information to diagnose the problem ANY time that it occurs ... not just when you've got assertion checking enabled.)

---

The backwards compatibility argument is possibly relevant.  However, as a general rule you *don't* write your code to run on old Java platforms.  If you have a *specific* requirement to support old versions of Java ... that's different.  But if that was the case, you shouldn't be doing your development against the Java 7 APIs at all ... so your compiler / IDE should flag the `Objects` class as compilation error.

(Restricting yourself to only using the older APIs when you don't need to will make your code quality suffer, and make it "out of date" earlier.  The *whole point* of the new stuff is to make it easier to write reliable / maintainable applications.  Deliberately not using it is ... perverse.  Imagine if you restricted yourself to Java 1.1 ...)

---

<sup>1 - FWIW, I think NPE's are just fine.  And NPE with a message is more specific than (say) `IllegalArgumentException`, and there's lots of precedents in the Java standard class libraries for constructors, etc that are *documented* as throwing NPEs.  Besides, this method was clearly designed to be used this way.</sup>

Comment: +1.. and as I said to @Ravi.. also think NPE is better (more specific) than IllegalArgumentException (or IStateExc)

Comment: `Will it slow your system down (due to lots of other assertion checks)?` No, because you can enable assertions selectively for just a package for example.

Comment: @Ravi - only if you know which package contains the class that contains the `assert` that would catch the problem.  And even then, there may be other **more expensive** `assert` checks in the class / package / whatever that you've selectively enabled assertions for.

Comment: @StephenC Usually when we enable something for a package we include all of its sub-packages as well. So, no you don't have to absolutely hit the bull's eye here. If one is not even able to pick the right candidate packages perhaps they are not familiar with their application's design.

Comment: @StephenC I know the code would take a slight performance hit with assertions enabled but let's not make it sound like we're doing RMI or calling EJBs suddenly. You take any other mechanism, say logging for example, to debug the code you would probably drop your log levels down to even `trace` and that would incur performance hit as well; in fact more so since I've rarely seen anybody using more than a `rootLogger` and it would then be tracing the entire application! And just like you'd switch your logger back to error/warn we won't be leaving assertions turned on once we've fixed the problem.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal - Actually, my main concerns with using `assert` are not the performance.  (If you are going to run with them turned on all the time, I assume that you would design the checks to be not-too-expensive.)  Rather, my concerns are 1) `assert` can be disabled and 2) enabling `assert` checks can *change* the behaviour of the application.

Answer (score 9):

I don't feel comfortable with the fact that `requireNonNull()` throws a `NullPointerException`. In my opinion, throwing the classic `IllegalArgumentException` makes the intention more clear. One can use `Assertions` as well with the advantage that they can be selectively turned on and off.

On the top of it, if you want to expose your code as a library one should *usually* make an effort to support the oldest JDK possible.

**EDIT**: I'd like to add that pick any well known framework today and you'll find that their APIs would always throw exceptions with names so descriptive you almost instantly get to know what's wrong.

To give an example, what happens when a Spring container finds that a `@Required` property on a managed bean could not be injected and so has remained`NULL`. You certainly don't get a `NullPointerException` with as descriptive an error message as possible.

You get a `BeanCreationException` wrapped around a `BeanInitializationException` giving further information about the member variable that is still `null` in a descriptive enough error message like: *Property 'center' is required for bean 'circle'.*

Comment: I disagree.. NullPointerException is, in my opinion, more suitable in this case because it clearly states that the problem is a `null` being passed where it cannot be (since we have a message). An IllegalArgument can be produced by anything wrong, the argumento should be greater than 0, value should be serializable, etc.

Comment: Yes, it does boil down a little bit to preference. But, personally I don't think my library code would generate much confidence if it starts throwing NullPointerExceptions. The default semantics that any Java programmer associates with it is that there's a bug in the code; *something is broken*. I would want to stay as far away as possible from it.

Comment: @Ravi - Many of the standard collection classes generate NPEs when called with `null` arguments, as do many other standard classes.  Does that make >>you<< feel less confident?  Sure, buggy code often produces NPEs, but it is not logical to make the reverse inference ... especially if you *document* the circumstances in which NPEs can be expected.  If someone assumes that an NPE means your code is buggy, they are idiots.

Comment: @StephenC I'm not trying to make a reverse inference. I'm just trying to **differentiate** between an actual occurrence of NPE and something that would lead to it but has been caught in time. A user passes some input which the app/lib fails to validate completely and passes on to a standard collection class which then throws an NPE. This certainly points to a bug and as a developer I've been made aware of it with the NPE. Once, I've put the required checks in place to *prevent* this NPE in future; I'd rather throw a more descriptive UnsatisfiedDependencyException than another NPE in its place.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have setters for `bar` and `baz`, you should do it in the setters:

```
public Foo(Bar bar, Baz baz) {
    setBar(bar);
    setBaz(baz);
}

public void setBar(Bar bar) {
    this.bar = Objects.requireNonNull(bar, "bar must not be null");
}

public void setBaz(Baz baz) {
    this.baz = Objects.requireNonNull(baz, "baz must not be null");
}
```

Otherwise the method you showed is fine.

Regarding the question about doing it at all - if your object is completely useless when `bar` and `baz` are null, you might as well do the null check at the constructor&setters. But if your object can be used when they are null - even if that usage is just checking that they are null and setting them with a setter, assuming that is a legitimate usage of your class - then you can let your users do it.